# How to get browser history using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var hlist = window.history.length; //length of history
var hisArr = [];    // empty array store prev history

    for ( i = 0; i <= hlist; i++ ) {
         hisArr.push( url );  
    };
```

Comment: But now i need that history in my local project .... pls give any idea...

Comment: var current = history.current;
var previous = history.previous;

When I run it I get

Error: uncaught exception: Permission denied to get property History.current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get url from history object, check the [manual](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp)

Comment: I think you could years back, but it was disabled for security reasons. http://www.gizmag.com/javascript-code-used-to-reveal-browser-history/17177/

Comment: @villu you can store history on server side, not an optimal solution, but at least something

Answer (score 0):

If you create a SPA application, the whole application will not reload when changing the page. AngularJS is an option for this, you can listen then to routeChange events and that way hold on to your own history.

If you only need the url's of your history, this can be a viable option.